# difeomorphism l<k or $l\geq k$

Tags: general-topology, functions, derivatives, continuity, diffeomorphism

I have just learned from Sikorski Book diferentiation of several variables this fact:

**there are no diffeomorphisms of $G\subseteq E^k$ to $G'\subseteq E^l$  for $l<k$ but they do exist for $l\geq k$.** It seems strange for me, as all conditions are completely symetrical between $E^k$ and $E^l$ for the definition of diffeomorphisms: $f$ and $f^{-1}
$ should exist and both should be of class $C^1$. Why this symmetry has been broken by possibility with $l\geq k$ and not for $l<k$ ? So why one direction is possible and  the other is not possible?

**EDIT: the source page**
[image]

Comment: You should provide a detailed quote. As written now, it is unclear what are the assumptions on $G, G'$ and without restrictions, the claim in the book is clearly wrong.

Comment: @MoisheKohan The book is in the Czech language and I have no other option than to scan it and put here the snippet. This practice is not well-accepted by some users, though. So wait a few hours till I manage it. Thank you.

Comment: It is the top of the page 223, the problem there is, to repeat, that $l\geq k$ is sometimes relevant. So my question is: can there be 2 open sets one in $E^k$ and one in $E^l$ that are homeomorphic ? for their choice $l\geq k$ ?

Comment: the rest of the chapter is obtainable from
[1](https://ibb.co/9GfgSdb)
[2](https://ibb.co/6NqhQyV)
[3](https://ibb.co/Dzn2Mnm) [4](https://ibb.co/BBYyjSP)

Comment: The right thing to do is to type the details in your question using MathJax for math. Also, make sure you are not confusing homeomorphisms and diffeomorphisms. Proofs for diffeomorphisms are much easier and bould down to linear algebra.

Comment: In any case, you should ponder the example where $G, G'$ are empty subsets.

Comment: For such a $\Phi: G\to G'$ and $p\in G$ the Jacobian $\Phi'(p)$ is a linear map from $E^k$ to $E^l$. For $l<k$ this linear map cannot be injective, so $\Phi$ cannot be regular.

Comment: @MarcOlschok And for $l > k$ nothing fails ?

Comment: @user122424: for $l\geq k$ a linear map from $E^k$ to $E^l$ at least has a chance to be injective. That is just linear algebra.

Comment: @MarcOlschok Of course. I just wonder why Sikorski considers anything like $k \neq l$ while the only way there can be a difeomorphism is when $k=l$.

Comment: @user122424: Yes indeed. As you can see, the determinant condition on top of the left page looks strange if you do consider different dimensions.